# Can we prevent creation of directory NODE0000 during db2 rollforward db <db_name> end of logs with overflow log path option?

Tags: db2, db2-luw, db2-10.5

I am using command `rollforward db ABCD to end of logs overflow log path ('/db2backup/logs')` to apply DB2 archived logs to my staging database. My staging database is in rollforward pending state.

Execution of command is fine when instance user have write permission on path /db2backup/log and execution of command is creating an empty directory structure as `NODE0000/LOGSTREAM0000/LOGSTREAM0000/`. I want to prevent any write access on path and still want to use same location for log apply.

Please let me know if it's possible to prevent creation of directory structure `NODE0000/LOGSTREAM0000/LOGSTREAM0000/` during execution of "rollforward db ABCD to end of logs overflow log path ('/db2backup/logs')".

Comment: Not sure I understand your requirements, can you elaborate on why you don't want db2 to create the necessary log structure?

Comment: The archive logs are available on a shared location and I can only read the logs and due storage I/O problem I can't copy these logs to some other location. So, I am looking for a way through which rollforward command can read the logs but directory structure will be created  in some other location

Comment: Are logfiles from remote server mounted in /db2backup/log?

Comment: Yes, the location is remote and mounted at /db2backup/logs

Comment: Problem is that db2 expects a certain structure below the overflow log path. Can you create that structure and mount there?

Comment: Yes, I tried same I created the expected directory structure (just for tes) where archived logs (remote location) are available and everything is working fine. But as per some restrictions I am not allowed to write anything on that remote shared location.